# How do I share data from child directives with parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

***I have edited this question to simplify it***

How can I share data from child directives with the grandparent's scope?

I want to get the data into the myData property

view:

```
<generator ng-model="myData"></generator>
myData={{myData|json}}
```

code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('generator', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      results: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<div ng-controller="generatorController"><div ng-repeat="field in fields"><child-widget field-name="{{field}}" ng-model="results[field]"></child-widget></div>results:{{results|json}}</div>'
  }
});
myApp.controller('generatorController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.fields = { fieldA: "A", fieldB: "B", fieldC: "C" };
  $scope.results = {};
}]);
myApp.directive('childWidget', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      fieldName: '@fieldName',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '{{fieldName}}: <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />'
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbRBL/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **a directive controller** instead of creating `ng-controller` inside your template

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IINXtsjpHrvrDViraQXn?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('generator', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      results: '=ngModel'
    },
    controller: 'generatorController',

    template: '<div ng-repeat="field in fields">' +
                 '<child-widget field-name="{{field}}" ng-model="results[field]"></child-widget>' +
              '</div>results:{{results|json}}'
  }
});
```

---

#### Why it did not work with `ng-controller`?

`ng-controller` always creates a new (non-isolated) scope.

So this is how the scopes tree looks like in your example:

```
| parent scope
| - generator scope   <====| no data
| --- controller scope  <==| binding
| ----- widget scope
```

- You made a two-way-binding between the **parent scope** and the **generator scope**
- You made a two-way-binding between the **controller scope** and the **widget scope**
- But there is no two-way-binding between the **generator scope** and the **controller scope**.

In my example there are only 3 scopes so it works:

```
| parent scope 
| - generator scope ( same as the controller's scope )
| --- widget scope
```

Comment: Excellent that works! Why did it not work the other way?

Comment: Thank you so much that makes a lot of things click for me!